# Accessing all 3 hives in the registry

Tags: delphi, registry, wmi, wow64

Creating a 32 bit application with delphi I do not have access to all hives depending whether the application is run on a win32 or win64 windows machine. Here is a link for default access: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390789(v=VS.85).aspx

I just want to create a single application, and not a separate version for 32 & 64. And I would like to use WMI and retrieve information from the 32 bit registry hive, the 64 bit registry hive and the WOW6432Node. There are FLAGS to set but I can't figure out how to send the flags with a regular WMI query call from my delphi application. Here is info about the FLAGs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393067(v=VS.85).aspx

GLibWmi & DelphiWmiCodeCreator exmple:

```
function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch; //create the Wmi instance
var
  chEaten: Integer;
  BindCtx: IBindCtx;
  Moniker: IMoniker;
begin
  OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
  OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));
  OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
end;

procedure  GetWin32_StartupCommandInfo;
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  objWMIService := GetWMIObject('winmgmts:\\localhost\root\CIMV2');
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_StartupCommand','WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln('');
  end;
end;
```

**REVISED CODE:**

```
procedure  GetWin32_StartupCommandInfo(aIDispatch: IDispatch);
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  objWMIService := aIDispatch; //GetWMIObject('winmgmts:\\localhost\root\CIMV2');
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_StartupCommand','WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    with Form1.lst1 do begin

      items.Add(Format('Caption="%s"; Location="%s"',[colItem.Caption,colItem.Location]));// String
      {items.Add(Format('Command         %s',[colItem.Command]));// String
      items.Add(Format('Description     %s',[colItem.Description]));// String
      items.Add(Format('Location        %s',[colItem.Location]));// String
      items.Add(Format('Name            %s',[colItem.Name]));// String
      items.Add(Format('SettingID       %s',[colItem.SettingID]));// String
      items.Add(Format('User            %s',[colItem.User]));// String
      items.Add(Format('UserSID         %s',[colItem.UserSID]));// String
      }
      items.Add('');

    end;
  end;
end;

function MyConnectWMI(wmiHost:string; var Services: ISWbemServices):Boolean;
const
  STR_CIM2_ROOT ='root\CIMV2';
  STR_EMPTY = '';
var
  NVS: SWbemNamedValueSet;
  providerArchitecture : OleVariant;
  requiredArchitecture : OleVariant;
  Locator : ISWbemLocator; //CoSWbemLocator;
begin
  try
    providerArchitecture := 32; // or 64
    requiredArchitecture := true;

    NVS := CoSWbemNamedValueSet.Create( );
    NVS.Add('__ProviderArchitecture', providerArchitecture , 0);
    NVS.Add('__RequiredArchitecture', requiredArchitecture , 0);
    // Create the Location object
    Locator := CoSWbemLocator.Create();
    // Connect to the WMI service, with the root\cimv2 namespace
    Services := Locator.ConnectServer(wmiHost,
        STR_CIM2_ROOT, {user}STR_EMPTY, {password}STR_EMPTY,
        STR_EMPTY,STR_EMPTY, 0, NVS);

    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aServices: ISWbemServices;
begin
  if MyConnectWMI('localhost', aServices) then
    GetWin32_StartupCommandInfo(aServices);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a WMI Moniker and as far as I can see you can't specify the options you need via it.  You need to use the SWbemLocator object instead as that let's you pass the SWbemNamedValueSet as the final parameter.

There is a ConnectWMI function in the UProcedures.pas file of GLibWMI.  It passes a nil to the final parm:

```
Services := Locator.ConnectServer(wmiHost,
        STR_CIM2_ROOT, {user}STR_EMPTY, {password}STR_EMPTY,
        STR_EMPTY,STR_EMPTY, 0, nil);
```

You need to create an alternative, something like this:

```
var
    NVS: SWbemNamedValueSet;
    providerArchitecture : OleVariant;
    requiredArchitecture : OleVariant;
/////

    providerArchitecture := 32; // or 64
    requiredArchitecture := true;

    NVS := CoSWbemNamedValueSet.Create();
    NVS.Add('__ProviderArchitecture', providerArchitecture , 0); 
    NVS.Add('__RequiredArchitecture', requiredArchitecture , 0);

    // Create the Location object
    Locator := CoSWbemLocator.Create();
    // Connect to the WMI service, with the root\cimv2 namespace
    Services := Locator.ConnectServer(wmiHost,
        STR_CIM2_ROOT, {user}STR_EMPTY, {password}STR_EMPTY,
        STR_EMPTY,STR_EMPTY, 0, NVS);
```

That will get you an ISWbemServices interface on which you can then execute ExecQuery.

Accessing the registry via StdRegProv -

```
procedure  Get_RegistryValue(aIDispatch: IDispatch);
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;

  strKeyPath : OLEVariant;
  strValue : OLEVariant;
  strOut : OLEVariant;

  objStdRegProv : OLEVariant;
begin;
  objWMIService := aIDispatch; 

  objStdRegProv := objWMIService.Get('StdRegProv');

  strKeyPath := 'Software\Microsoft\Wbem\CIMOM';
  strValue := 'Logging';

  objStdRegProv.GetStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValue, strOut);

    with Form1.lst1 do begin
      items.Add(strOut);
    end;
  end;
end;


// connect to root\default instead of cimv2
function MyConnectWMI(wmiHost:string; var Services: ISWbemServices):Boolean;
const
  STR_DEFAULT_ROOT = 'root\default'
  STR_EMPTY = '';
var
  NVS: SWbemNamedValueSet;
  providerArchitecture : OleVariant;
  requiredArchitecture : OleVariant;
  Locator : ISWbemLocator; //CoSWbemLocator;
begin
  try
    providerArchitecture := 32; // or 64
    requiredArchitecture := true;

    NVS := CoSWbemNamedValueSet.Create( );
    NVS.Add('__ProviderArchitecture', providerArchitecture , 0);
    NVS.Add('__RequiredArchitecture', requiredArchitecture , 0);
    // Create the Location object
    Locator := CoSWbemLocator.Create();
    // Connect to the WMI service, with the root\cimv2 namespace
    Services := Locator.ConnectServer(wmiHost,
        STR_DEFAULT_ROOT, {user}STR_EMPTY, {password}STR_EMPTY,
        STR_EMPTY,STR_EMPTY, 0, NVS);

    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I got it to work, but only when the providerArchitecture is set at 64, if I have it set at 32 I get a EOleException error: "Provider Load Fail". I'm running Win7 64Bit with Delphi 2010.

Comment: CHeck above in my original post in the REVISED section. THe code BREAKs when the "ExecQuery" is executed and not when I create the connection.

Comment: This will be down to providers.  Win32_StartupCommand is supplied by the Win32 provider, not the registry provider.  This page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394570%28v=VS.85%29.aspx lists the providers.  The registry provider mentions two versions on 64 bit platforms.

Comment: I've added code that uses the registry provider StdRegProv.  This does connect to the 32 and 64 bit hives under win 7 64bit.  If you want to use Win32_StartupCommand you'll have to detect the O/S first or handle the exception.